# Looking for a sample project with Kafka->Storm

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

I'm looking for a website where to download a sample project that contains both KAFKA and STORM (with NoSQL it should be better).
Anybody can help me ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have put an example of basic aggregation/persistence usage based on Storm, Kafka and Cassandra here on github:

https://github.com/svendx4f/stormRoomOccupancy

There's a detailed explanation of how it works on my blog:

http://svendvanderveken.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/scalable-real-time-state-update-with-storm/

Comment: Great ! Thank's a lot Svend, I'm studying your really nice project. See you.